# Navigation on top instead of header

Tags: javascript, html, css

The navigation in my HTML-file should be seen at the top. So theoretically you can scroll up to see the header. Do you know what i mean? I'll show it with 2 images.

PS: I don't want to use hashtags, cause i need it already for other stuff. 

**Edit**: When you call the page, it should look like in image #1.

normal state:
[image: without header]
If you now scroll up, the header should appear.
[image: with header]

Comment: I take it that you really mean that image #2 would be how the page would appear when it first loads? And when a user scrolls down the page the NAV element would stick to the top of the page? And when they scroll back up the page the HEADER would become visible again? If so then this is probably what you want: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/fixedfloat.html

Comment: And what is your actual question? There's only a description, how you want your page to work in the post.

Comment: @BillyMoat No, the #1 image would be how the page would appear when it first loads.

Comment: I think Billy already described the question. The navigation should always be on the top of the page (when scrolled down) but not as far on top that it'll cover the header/banner (when scrolled to the top)

Comment: @Sylnois - Fair enough, but it would seem strange to hide the website's branding when the page first loads. I don't recall ever seeing that done before and can't think of a good reason why you would do it.

Comment: @BillyMoat, I've seen many times on mobile sites

Comment: @BillyMoat My Template has a really big header with information, that you only need if you run the index.php. If you now click on any menu, the header is no longer interessting, but you should have the possibility that you can scroll up to see the header.

Comment: @I.G.Pascual - I don't think we're talking about a mobile site. No big deal though. It was just an observation on my part that it was unusual behaviour. I'm not saying it's right or wrong.

Comment: I've got it: `if(location.pathname != "/") document.getElementById('navigation').scrollIntoView(true);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood your "question" correctly, you can try this:

```
      <script>
          document.getElementById('navigation').scrollIntoView(true);
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, this is it. Now i just want to get it worked if you call index.php, cause it works only if i click on a menupoint(it just calls another html-file with the same js-script included).

Answer (score 1):

I think, you are searching for `.scrollTop()` of jQuery or something similar. Maybe this helps: http://www.backslash.gr/demos/jquery-sticky-navigation/

Comment: #Linus Caldwell I don't want that the navigation stays on top. I just want when someone call the page, the navigation should be at the top first. So you have still the possibility to scroll up for the headerinformation.

Comment: Which you could achieve with `.scrollTop()` too. Or just give Teemu's hint a try.